# dcm4che storescp using tls and pem files

Tags: dcm4che

In Dcmtk Working with key and cert is quite straight forward and everything is working as expected.
But, When Using Dcm4che storescp , I cannot understand how to use tls , and add key and cert pem files.
If This function is exists I Would be happy for an Syntax Example for how to use it

https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che/tree/master/dcm4che-tool/dcm4che-tool-storescp

In Dcmtk the command is as follows :

```
sudo storescp --verbose --debug --enable-tls [key.pem] [crt.pem] --add-cert-file [ca] --output-directory /home/test/dicom_files -B  443
```

Thanks!